# skip updating created_at column while using gorm Update with associations

Tags: go-gorm

**Background**
We are using [gorm association](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html) as we have nested hierarchy. We are using [Create()](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-Record) for creation of records across multiple tables and Updates opeartion for updating the records.
While doing the update, we first fetch complete hierarchy, update it and then invoke update().

**Issue**
During the update we do not want to change the created_at timestamp.
For top level struct/ record, this is working fine and created_at column is not updated. However, for nested records created_at timestamp is changed always on performing update operation. On update, we just want to update the updated_at column and keep created_at intact.

Structs:

```
    struct A { 
      ID                     string          `gorm:"column:id;type:char(36); not null;primary_key"`
      B                      []*B            `gorm:"foreignKey:AID;references:ID"`
      CreatedAt              time.Time       `gorm:"column:created_at;type:timestamp; not null"`
      UpdatedAt              time.Time       `gorm:"column:updated_at;type:timestamp; not null"`
    }
         
        
    struct B {
      ID                       string     `gorm:"column:id;type:char(36); not null;primary_key"`
      AID                      string     `gorm:"column:aid;type:char(36); not null"`
      C                        []*C       `gorm:"foreignKey:BID;references:ID"`
      CreatedAt                time.Time  `gorm:"column:created_at;type:timestamp; not null"`
      UpdatedAt                time.Time  `gorm:"column:updated_at;type:timestamp; not null"`
   }
    
   struct C {
      ID                       string     `gorm:"column:id;type:char(36); not null;primary_key"`
      BID                      string     `gorm:"column:bid;type:char(36); not null"`
      CreatedAt                time.Time  `gorm:"column:created_at;type:timestamp; not null"`
      UpdatedAt                time.Time  `gorm:"column:updated_at;type:timestamp; not null"`
 }
```

Below is the snippet of code how we are updating the records:

```
txn.Session(&gorm.Session{Context: ctx, FullSaveAssociations: true}).
        Updates(record)
```

**Query Executed:**

1. UPDATE `A` SET `updated_at`=? WHERE `id` = ?
2. INSERT INTO `B` (`id`, `aid`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=VALUES(`id`), `aid`=(`aid`),`created_at`=VALUES(),`updated_at`=VALUES(`updated_at`)
3. INSERT INTO `C` (`id`, `bid`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=VALUES(`id`), `bid`=(`aid`),`created_at`=VALUES(),`updated_at`=VALUES(`updated_at`)

**Things tried:**

1. Omit: we have tried using db.omit("B.CreatedAt, B.C.CreatedAt"). However, this is not working.
2. <-:create: This leads to failure in Unit tests with reason: there is a remaining expectation which was not matched. Essentially, nested records are not persisted.